# CSS Zoom in Google Maps with iOS / Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I have an iPad App which includes a Google Map. On that Map I can draw lines and place markers with Google Map API V3. All done with jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap.

The Problem I have is that I need a higher Zoom on the Map, than Google provides me. 
I did that with setting CSS scale to the Google Map div. The Zoom is working.

The problem is:

If I place Markers on the zoomed Map they are not on the Place, where I click. They appear somewhere else on the map, because of the Div Zoom is changing coordinates. 
If I scale the App on iPad, it is working. However I only want to scale the map and not the whole app.

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Comment: Link to your code and CSS would be valuable.

Comment: the function called when zoom is this:

// Karte mit CSS grösser Zoomen
 function FSuperZoom(wert) {
  ZoomWert = wert/10;
  $("#map_canvas > div > div:first-child").css("-moz-transform","scale("+ZoomWert+","+ZoomWert+")");
  $("#map_canvas > div > div:first-child").css("-webkit-transform","scale("+ZoomWert+","+ZoomWert+")");
  $("#map_canvas > div > div:first-child").css("-o-transform","scale("+ZoomWert+","+ZoomWert+")");
  $("#map_canvas > div > div:first-child").css("transform","scale("+ZoomWert+","+ZoomWert+")");

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`<meta name="viewport">`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) tag to control scaling.

---

Don't use CSS zoom. Use the `setZoom` method on the `Map` object in the Maps API.

See [the reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map).

Comment: Thanks, but i need higher Zoom than the setZoom can do.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Since you're on iPad, have you considered changing the `<meta name="viewport">` tag?

Comment: yes i did that, then I can zoom the whole app and it is working. but i dont want to zoom all, I want to Zoom just the Map. If I Finger Pinch on the Map it Zooms, but it goes back to max Zoom of google just after release the finger from the map.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your approach by using the `zoom` CSS property (which should be supported by iOS WebKit) instead of a CSS transform.  So your `FSuperZoom` function becomes

```
function FSuperZoom(wert) {
  ZoomWert = wert/10;
  $("#map_canvas > div > div:first-child").css("zoom",ZoomWert);
}
```

Comment: The Zoom is working with your Solution also, but I still have the Problem if I place a Marker on the Zoomed Map, it does not appear on the place I clicked.